# Want to know about html and php

Tags: php, html, css

I'm new to web design. I started with html and make some pages with ext .html
but now I want to add a contact us form or message us form in my html page . So how can I do that . Actually I want to use html page and that html page can execute php script.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in your contact form .html give a action of php page and need to make one php page for send contact detail via mail function.

Comment: Thanks dear. but I want to know in details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create html page like contact.html and put below code

```
 <form action="email.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <fieldset>
         <label><span class="text-red">*</span> Full name:</label>
         <input type="text" id="contact-name" name="mname" required/>
       </fieldset>

       <fieldset>
         <label><span class="text-red">*</span> Email:</label>
         <input type="email" name="email" id="contact-email" required/>
       </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
          <label>Link to your portfolio or personal website (Optional)</label>
         <input type="text" id="portfolio-link"  name="mlink"/>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
         <label><span class="text-red">*</span> Message:</label>
         <textarea rows="5" id="contact-message" name="mmsg" required></textarea>
        </fieldset>

   <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submitmail" />
                        </form>
```

Now create something like email.php and put below code

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitmail'])) 
  {
    $name=$_POST['mname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $link= $_POST['mlink'];
    $message  = $_POST ['mmsg'];

        $headers .= "From: Display title ";
    $message = 'Name: '.$name."\r\n".'Email: '.$email."\r\n". 'Portfolio / Website Link: '.$link."\r\n". 'Message: '.$message ;

    $mail= mail("abc@yourdomain.com" , "Feedback/Query" , $message , $headers);

if ($mail == true)  {
        echo "<script>alert('Thank you. We will contact you soon..!!');</script>";
 } 
 else 
      {
         echo "<script>alert('Something is not right. Please try again.');</script>";
    }  
  } 
 ?>
```

remember, mail function only works if your localhost has a setup, otherwise you need to use smtp like phpmailer or something .. there is always a best practice to use phpmailer instead of mail function of php.

Comment: Edit : 
<form action="email.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: So I can use .php as separate file? but what is php mailer??

Comment: yes here in above example, we have used seperate php file to send email ..

Comment: for more information about php mailer, read this https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: upvote my answer if you find it useful .. thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot bro, I'm a new user of stackoverflow , may be that's why my up vote didn't work. it says 15 reputation needed.

Comment: Sir, can I use this method for MySQL data entry ?

Comment: @SumonTito you can choose my answer as best answer from the list if you find it helpful.

Comment: @SumonTito  yes you can use mysql in email.php file by connecting your mysql in that file and inserting a record by creating a query in email.php file as well.

Comment: Ok thank you sir :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this..You can use PhpMailer or any other Mailer you prefer to send mail to other servers. This code will work on your server only.

```
 <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <fieldset>
         <label><span class="text-red">*</span> Full name:</label>
         <input type="text" id="contact-name" name="mname" required/>
       </fieldset>

       <fieldset>
         <label><span class="text-red">*</span> Email:</label>
         <input type="email" name="email" id="contact-email" required/>
       </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
          <label>Link to your portfolio or personal website (Optional)</label>
         <input type="text" id="portfolio-link"  name="mlink"/>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
         <label><span class="text-red">*</span> Message:</label>
         <textarea rows="5" id="contact-message" name="mmsg" required></textarea>
        </fieldset>

   <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submitmail" />
                        </form>



  <?php
if (isset($_POST['submitmail'])) 
  {
    $name=$_POST['mname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $link= $_POST['mlink'];
    $message  = $_POST ['mmsg'];

        $headers .= "From: Display title ";
    $message = 'Name: '.$name."\r\n".'Email: '.$email."\r\n". 'Portfolio / Website Link: '.$link."\r\n". 'Message: '.$message ;

    $mail= mail("abc@yourdomain.com" , "Feedback/Query" , $message , $headers);

if ($mail == true)  {
        echo "<script>alert('Thank you. We will contact you soon..!!');</script>";
 } 
 else 
      {
         echo "<script>alert('Something is not right. Please try again.');</script>";
    }  
  } 
 ?>
```

Comment: Can I load php script from a separate file?